# Parsing Command Line and alter it into Char or Boolean

Tags: java, parsing, command-line, casting

Im in need of an option to parse the command line for a TicTacToe Game.
Player 1 & 2 Name .... Player 1 & 2 sign as (char) and isP1(P2)Ai as (boolean).

```
 TicTacToe ttt = new TicTacToe();

    Options options = new Options();

    Option p1Name = new Option("-p1name", "--player1Name", false, "The name for Player 1");
    p1Name.setRequired(false);
    options.addOption(p1Name);

    Option p1Sign = new Option("-p1sign", "--player1Sign", false, "The sign for Player 1");
    p1Sign.setRequired(false);
    options.addOption(p1Sign);

    Option p2Name = new Option("-p2name", "--player2Name", false, "The name for Player 2");
    p2Name.setRequired(false);
    options.addOption(p2Name);

    Option p2Sign = new Option("-p2sign", "--player2Sign", false, "The sign for Player 2");
    p2Sign.setRequired(false);
    options.addOption(p2Sign);

    Option p1IsAi = new Option("-isP1Ai", "--isPlayer1Ai", false, "Determine if Player 1 should be an AI");
    p1IsAi.setRequired(false);
    options.addOption(p1IsAi);

    Option p2IsAi = new Option("-isP2Ai", "--isPlayer2Ai", false, "Determine if Player 2 should be an AI");
    p2IsAi.setRequired(false);
    options.addOption(p2IsAi);

    CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();
    HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
    CommandLine cmd = null;

    try
    {
        cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        formatter.printHelp("utility-name", options);

        System.exit(1);
    }

    String player1Name = cmd.getOptionValue("p1Name");
    String player2Name = cmd.getOptionValue("p2Name");
    char player1Sign = cmd.getOptionValue("p1sign");
    char player2Sign = cmd.getOptionValue("p2sign");
    String boolP1 = cmd.getOptionValue("p1IsAi");
    String boolP2 = cmd.getOptionValue("p2IsAi");
    boolean isPlayer1Ai = Boolean.valueOf(boolP1);
    boolean isPlayer2Ai = Boolean.valueOf(boolP2);

    if (args.length == 4)
    {
        Player player1 = new Player(player1Name, player1Sign, isPlayer1Ai);
        Player player2 = new Player(player2Name, player2Sign, isPlayer2Ai);
        ttt = new TicTacToe(player1, player2);
    }
    ttt.run();
}
```

So the Problem is :

When i try to get the argument for isPlayer1(2)Ai

boolean isPlayer1Ai = Boolean.valueOf(boolP1);

boolean isPlayer2Ai = Boolean.valueOf(boolP2);

It facts that it is auto unboxed into boolean ... is that somehow a Problem ?

And how can i parse the sign of an player, like i tried but failed, out of the command line and cast it to char?

The Constructor for my Players :

```
 public Player(String name, char sign, boolean isPlayerAi)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.sign = sign;
    this.isPlayerAi = isPlayerAi;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, `cmd.getOptionValue` will always return a String, even if it's just a single character. To convert a single-char String to a character, you could use `.charAt(0)`: *get the first (0-indexed) character of a String*. So, assuming the player-sign values cannot be `null` nor empty, change these two lines:

```
char player1Sign = cmd.getOptionValue("p1sign");
char player2Sign = cmd.getOptionValue("p2sign");
```

to:

```
char player1Sign = cmd.getOptionValue("p1sign").charAt(0);
char player2Sign = cmd.getOptionValue("p2sign").charAt(0);
```

---

As for your other question about the autoboxing of `Boolean` to `boolean`, that again depends on whether the Strings can be `null` and/or empty and/or invalid. If they are always either `true` or `false`, autoboxing to a `boolean`-primitive should be fine. If not, an if-check is again required, and perhaps `Boolean` objects holding `true`/`false`/`null` should be used instead.

---

Since I don't know what your code should do, I don't know if they can be `null`, and/or empty Strings, and/or invalid Strings. Nor do I know what they should be instead after converting them to `boolean`/`char` (or `Boolean`/`Character`). So I left that in the open for now..

Comment: I´ve got that thanks.  My Code should create Players for the TicTacToe, and it should be with the option isAi that it is an ComputerAi Enemy ... with logic coded by me. So i´ve altered my code for Ai´s to:       boolean isPlayer1Ai = cmd.hasOption("isP1Ai");
        boolean isPlayer2Ai = cmd.hasOption("isP2Ai");
So when either Option isP1Ai has been given in the Command Line this player is an ai so it returns a true.

Comment: New Problem : I cant initialize -> "CommandLine cmd;" .  It facts that  the variable may not have been initialized. Quick Tip is to "CommandLine cmd = null;"   the result is that "String player1Name = cmd.getOptionValue("p1Name");"  the value is null and finally on : "char player1Sign = cmd.getOptionValue("p1Sign").charAt(0);"  it throws an null pointer.